# How to calculate the listview Item height at run time and set all items with same height in android?

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

In my application i have a list view and i am inflating a web view into the list view. I am able to load data and images into the list view item. The problem is the  list items  are not of same height due to different contents. I want to make all list items having same height

How to calculate the height of the list item that has the maximum data and set that height to rest of the list items in the list.

How would i do that.. i have no clue on that.. Say if the 10th item has the maximum height i want to apply that height to the rest. help me implement this please and thank you for your support

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wv1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: can you post the inflating xml, here so that some one can help you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have an array of flags, say

```
boolean[] flags=new boolean[szieOfList];
```

fill this array to false;

Have a variable max height in your activity or adapter, say max, initialize it with 0 in onCreate method, now in getView method where you are inflating xml, write the following code:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view= (WebView) layoutInflater
            .inflate(R.layout.web_view, null);
if(flag[position])
{
      LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
              params.height = max;
              view.setLayoutParams(params);
}     
ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        //in here, place the code that requires you to know the dimensions.

         flag[position]=true;
         int height= view.getHeight();
         if(max<height)
         {
              max=height;
              notifyDataSetInvalidated();
         }
          else
         {
               LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
              params.height = max;
              view.setLayoutParams(params);
         }
         //this will be called as the layout is finished, prior to displaying.
    }
}
```

Comment: what does this line for boolean[] flags=new boolean[szieOfList]; and here size of list will be null right?

Comment: Its size of list, from which you are loading data in listView, in your case, It is array length.